# Wordpress: Hook before "New Page" trigger will be fired

Tags: wordpress, hook

i want to set a limit of 5 pages (for example)!

So every time the users is clicking on "New Page" I want to check / count the exisiting pages in the Database.

I have only found things like this in the wp documentation

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_pages_page

My Target: If the max page qnty alread exists an error message will be displayed. Otherwise the typical Page creation process will be triggered...

Thx for any hint or suggestion :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Where's the code you attempted to make this work? WP has many different ways of doing what you are asking, but we don't know how you're trying to accomplish it. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

**solution was**

```
wp_count_posts( 'page' )->publish
```

WIth this funtion you will get all pages / page quantity of your published pages....

Hope this helps also other users :)

bye